# Conectar a uma base de dados local c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017

Qual é a sintaxe correta do SqlConnection para ligar a uma base de dados local?
Penso que seja qlq coisa deste genero!!

```
    SqlConnection liga = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;
                      AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\BaseDeDados.mdf;
                      Integrated Security=True;
                      Connect Timeout=30");
```

Comment: para ver a sintaxe da string de conexão, acesse: https://www.connectionstrings.com/ e para ver a sintaxe do `SqlConnection` acesse: https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use dessa forma, é o mais recomendado, utilizando a keyword **using**.

```
var connectionString = @"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;
                      AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\BaseDeDados.mdf;
                      Integrated Security=True;
                      Connect Timeout=30";

using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    con.Open();

    using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Table", con))
    using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
    {
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            // Leitura do seu Reader
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: muito obrigado!!!!